# Disable XP unsigned driver warning from recovery CD

Tags: windows-xp, installation

This is an extremely stupid situation. I am restoring an XP install, and everything goes fine up to the point where it is "installing devices".

There, the unsigned driver warning appears for my audio card (I know the driver works).

It asks me whether I want to continue installation anyway, but as it is in the phase of installing devices, my keyboard and mouse do not work yet so I cannot tell it to continue.

Is there any way to continue the installation?
I thought about disabling the warning for the driver, is that possible to do from the Recovery Console of the installation CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I used a linux live cd to look at the windows drive, and then I went into C:\Windows\inf and deleted the oem .inf file of the driver by greping the inf files for the name of the driver as to disable it, and now it installed fine!

Answer (score 0):

What type of keyboard are you using?, You should use either a PS2 or a usb (non wireless), if it is a usb, try another usb port.

You need to solve the keyboard issue.

Comment: It's a USB wireless keyboard. However, it works fine, it just stops working for a while during that "installing devices" phase. Unfortunately I have no PS2 or non-wireless keyboard.

Comment: You need one to solve this problem, they are cheap these days.